# Lightroom database corrupted after recovery

Tags: database, sqlite, encryption, corruption, lightroom

I am trying to rebuild an Adobe Lightroom catalog file which is basically a SQLite database. In this case the file was accidently deleted and recovered using Disk Drill. When I use .dump to create an SQL file, I only get a very small file out of there original 5.5GB catalog file and it is useless. If I try to open the file in DB browser for SQLite it thinks it is encrypted and asks for a password. Any suggestions how I could fix that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Contact Adobe support maybe?

Comment: The data was not recovered. You have a file full of garbage data. You must restore the database file from the backup.

Comment: First off / thanks Pierre and CL for the quick response. @CL: The person who sent me the file hasn't done a Lightroom backup for quite a while, so all have to go on is this recovered file. But are you saying that a recovered database file is generally useless?

Comment: I don't know about "generally", but this particular file does not contain the original data.

Comment: That's why i said "generally" because it sounds like the way recovery software handles databases they don't end up having the original data. Thanks again.